# rdlc report row totals field not calculating correctly

Tags: c#, time, rdlc, time-and-attendance

Good Day

I have a rdlc report on my time and attendance solution,
but the totals field keeps giving me the wrong value...

[image: Report Sample]

```
=IIF(((TimeSpan.Parse(Fields!HoursNT.Value)+TimeSpan.Parse(Fields!HoursOT1.Value)+TimeSpan.Parse(Fields!HoursOT2.Value)+TimeSpan.Parse(Fields!HoursOT3.Value)+TimeSpan.Parse(Fields!HoursOT4.Value))).Minutes.ToString().Length=1,string.Format("{0}:0{1}",Convert.ToInt32(((TimeSpan.Parse(Fields!HoursNT.Value)+TimeSpan.Parse(Fields!HoursOT1.Value)+TimeSpan.Parse(Fields!HoursOT2.Value)+TimeSpan.Parse(Fields!HoursOT3.Value)+TimeSpan.Parse(Fields!HoursOT4.Value))).TotalHours),((TimeSpan.Parse(Fields!HoursNT.Value)+TimeSpan.Parse(Fields!HoursOT1.Value)+TimeSpan.Parse(Fields!HoursOT2.Value)+TimeSpan.Parse(Fields!HoursOT3.Value)+TimeSpan.Parse(Fields!HoursOT4.Value))).Minutes),string.Format("{0}:{1}",Convert.ToInt32(((TimeSpan.Parse(Fields!HoursNT.Value)+TimeSpan.Parse(Fields!HoursOT1.Value)+TimeSpan.Parse(Fields!HoursOT2.Value)+TimeSpan.Parse(Fields!HoursOT3.Value)+TimeSpan.Parse(Fields!HoursOT4.Value))).TotalHours),((TimeSpan.Parse(Fields!HoursNT.Value)+TimeSpan.Parse(Fields!HoursOT1.Value)+TimeSpan.Parse(Fields!HoursOT2.Value)+TimeSpan.Parse(Fields!HoursOT3.Value)+TimeSpan.Parse(Fields!HoursOT4.Value))).Minutes))
```

This is the expression for the Total field...

What am I doing wrong?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was a noob mistake

I made a test program to illustrate The solution

[image: test project]

the total hours from 8:37 came to 8.61666666666667
converting it to an int  came to 9
but casting it to an int gave me the desired 8

[image: Code for 3 buttons]

But when applying this to rdlc report, casting `(int)` wouldn't work... So I used `Math.Truncate`

```
=IIF(((TimeSpan.Parse(Fields!HoursNT.Value)+TimeSpan.Parse(Fields!HoursOT1.Value)+TimeSpan.Parse(Fields!HoursOT2.Value)+TimeSpan.Parse(Fields!HoursOT3.Value)+TimeSpan.Parse(Fields!HoursOT4.Value))).Minutes.ToString().Length=1,string.Format("{0}:0{1}",Math.Truncate(((TimeSpan.Parse(Fields!HoursNT.Value)+TimeSpan.Parse(Fields!HoursOT1.Value)+TimeSpan.Parse(Fields!HoursOT2.Value)+TimeSpan.Parse(Fields!HoursOT3.Value)+TimeSpan.Parse(Fields!HoursOT4.Value))).TotalHours).ToString("F0"),((TimeSpan.Parse(Fields!HoursNT.Value)+TimeSpan.Parse(Fields!HoursOT1.Value)+TimeSpan.Parse(Fields!HoursOT2.Value)+TimeSpan.Parse(Fields!HoursOT3.Value)+TimeSpan.Parse(Fields!HoursOT4.Value))).Minutes),string.Format("{0}:{1}",Math.Truncate(((TimeSpan.Parse(Fields!HoursNT.Value)+TimeSpan.Parse(Fields!HoursOT1.Value)+TimeSpan.Parse(Fields!HoursOT2.Value)+TimeSpan.Parse(Fields!HoursOT3.Value)+TimeSpan.Parse(Fields!HoursOT4.Value))).TotalHours).ToString("F0"),((TimeSpan.Parse(Fields!HoursNT.Value)+TimeSpan.Parse(Fields!HoursOT1.Value)+TimeSpan.Parse(Fields!HoursOT2.Value)+TimeSpan.Parse(Fields!HoursOT3.Value)+TimeSpan.Parse(Fields!HoursOT4.Value))).Minutes))
```

Hope This Could Help Someone!